# how to make simple datimepicker in ASP.net VB

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, vb.net

I have simple question is that, how to make Datetime picker in Asp.net VB?

Im new in ASP.net need your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use input field with `type="date"`

**Plain HTML**

```html
<input id="date" type="date">
```

For ASP.NET control:

```
 <asp:TextBox runat="server" type="date" />
```

ref for more options https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date

Using jQuery UI plugin:

You should check out the [jQuery UI DatePicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/).

ASP.NET Example

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#<%= txtDate.ClientID %>" ).datepicker();
});
</script>

<form id="form1" runat="server">
  <div>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" runat="server" />
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: i have do this but i cannot get the date value because it is cannot runnat server in asp.net

Comment: @Indrasuandi check my updated answer with jquery UI plugin

Comment: as u'r references JQuery how can I get or download  it's css and JS file?

Comment: @Indrasuandi you can download it from http://jqueryui.com/download/ select your required controls